# Sending solr data to solr cloud directly

Tags: solr

I'm rather new to Solr and I need help understanding how to do this procedure or if it can even be done.

I have a local solr instance running that indexes data for me. I am trying to send this already indexed information to a solr cloud.

Is there a way of just sending the data folder (the index and tlog folders) of your solr instance to the solr cloud?

Thank you!

EDIT:

The solution to the problem:
To restate the actual problem, we are trying to add different types of collections on Solr. To add onto the cloud from a local server, you can do this:
1. Create collection in Solr Cloud
2. Put your data file in the collection (you should name the collection to something unique and descriptive).
3. Reload the collection otherwise you will not be able to see the data.

Comment: Is there any reason why your Solr node isn`t a member of your solr cloud cluster?

Comment: I believe it has to do with time and space costs as well as having asynchronous processes, but I am not too sure. I'll have a chat with my co-workers about this later.

Comment: Seing as there's more to indexing than just copying the files when running as a cluster (distributing the content to different servers for sharding and replication according to the cluster setup), you need to find out what you're actually trying to solve first :-)

Comment: OH! you are right. I talked to some of the others and basically the idea is that we are going to create multiple collections in the cloud, each of one shard. Thanks for that. I'm going to write my solution on the answer above in case anyone ever needs it.